# How can I groupby rows by the columns in which they actually posses a data point?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I don't even know if groupby is the correct function to use for this. It's a bit hard to understand so Ill include a screenshot of my dataframe: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1VIE.png)

Basically, this dataframe has way too many columns because each column is specific to only one or a few rows. You can see in the screenshot that the first few columns are specific towards the first row and the last few columns are specific to the last row. I want to make it so that each row only has the columns that actually pertain to it. I've tried several methods of using groupby('equipment name') and several methods using dropna but none work in the way I need it to. I'm also open to separating it into multiple dataframes.

Any method is acceptable, this bug has been driving me crazy. It took me a while to get to this point because this started out as an unintelligible 10,000 line json. I'm pretty new to programming as well.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  By your image, I think you necessarily can't have the first and the last row in the same DF without having many NaNs.  Maybe you can give a picture, or a phony DataFrame showing the desired output?  I can't tell exactly what you are looking for (and I don't think `groupby` is right), but there maybe an option to convert the data that is more manageable

Comment: @Tom Hey man, thanks and thank you for responding. Yes, I want it to look like this for each group of rows that shares the same columns: https://i.imgur.com/r0k8fqJ.png. This is actually the original data in a pdf. I want to be able to compare it 1:1 with the original data tables to check for errors quickly. Im starting to realize there is no way around having  multiple dataframes. However, one dataframe with a bunch of columns only pertaining to one or a few rows is def not the solution either, haha. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: For future reference, it is best to post your issue with a minimal, reproducible example ([MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), the original post in the answer I linked is a great example of this!), say a small amount of toy data illustrating the problem.  It was difficult to read your images, and an example with code and data is more likely to get fast responses : )

Comment: Hey @Tom thanks so much for your answer. I think the solution you linked may be a big step for me, although the nature of this data (mechanical schedule) is that rows won't always share the exact same columns. My question now is, how can I take this new dictionary made from this and export it to some kind of dataframe/dataframes? So I can actually compare the data on the pdf and this data I created 1:1. Let me know how I can credit you for these answers as well.

Comment: I just expanded my answer, hopefully something in there helps!  In general, if an answer answers your question you should accept it.  If not, you can comment why it doesn't, elaborate on your question, or upvote if it was helpful (but didn't solve the problem) : D

Comment: @Tom This is perfect. I actually figured out a way to do it using ExcelWriter along with the answer you linked me to earlier so I'm all good now, but this answer is really great and I'm certain I will be using it in the near future. I accepted your answer and upvoted it but nobody can see my upvotes because I don't have enough points :). Thank you again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This is a very cool answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52502214/13386979) that could be one option - and it does use `groupby` so sorry for dismissing!!!  This will group your data into DataFrames where each DataFrame has a unique group of columns, and any row which only contains values for those columns will be in that DataFrame.  If your data are such that there are multiple groups of rows which share the *exact same columns*, this solution is ideal I think.

Just to note, though, if your null values are more randomly spread out throughout the dataset, or if one row in a group of rows is missing a single entry (compared to related rows), you will end up with more combinations of unique non-null columns, and then more output DataFrames.

There are also (in my opinion) nice ways to search a DataFrame, even if it is very sparse. You can check the non-null values for a row:

```
df.loc[index_name].dropna()
```

Or for an index number:

```
df.iloc[index_number].dropna()
```

You could further store these values, say in a dictionary (this is a dictionary of `Series`, but could be converted to `DataFrame`:

```
row_dict = {row : df.loc[row].dropna() for row in df.index}
```

I could imagine some scenarios where something based off these options is more helpful for searching.  But that linked answer is slick, I would try that.

---

**EDIT:** Expanding on the answer above based on comments with OP.

The dictionary created in the linked post *contain the DataFrames* .  Basically you can use this dictionary to do comparisons with the original source data.  My only issue with that answer was that it may be hard to search the dictionary if the column names are janky (as it looks like in your data), so here's a slight modification:

```
for i, (name,df) in enumerate(df.groupby(df.isnull().dot(df.columns))):
    d['df' + str(i)] = df.dropna(1)
```

Now the dictionary keys are "df#", and the values are the DataFrames.  So if you wanted to inspect the content one DataFrame, you can call:

```
d['df1'].head()

#OR

print(d['df0'])
```

If you wanted to look at all the DataFrames, you could call

```
for df in d.values():
    print(df.head()) #you can also pass an integer to head to show more rows than 5
```

Or if you wanted to save each DataFrame you could call:

```
for name in sorted(d.keys()):
   d[name].to_csv('path/to/file/' + name + '.csv')
```

The point is, you've gotten to a data structure where you can look at the original data, separated into DataFrames without missing data.  Joining these back into a single DataFrame would be redundant, as it would create a single DataFrame (equal to the original) or multiple with some amount of missing data.

I think it comes down to what you are looking for and how you need to search the data.  You could rename the dictionary keys / output .CSV files based on the types of machinery inside, for example.

I thought your last comment might mean that objects of similar type might not share the same columns; say for example if not all "Exhaust Fans" have the same columns, they will end up in different DataFrames in the dictionary.  This maybe the type of case where it might be easier to just look at individual rows, rather than grouping them into weird categories:

```
df_dict = {row : pd.DataFrame(df.loc[row].dropna()).transpose() for row in df.index}
```

You could again then save these DataFrames as CSV files or look at them one by one (or e.g. search for Exhaust Fans by seeing if `"Exhaust"` is in they key).  You could also print them all at once:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import natsort

#making some randomly sparse data
columns = ['Column ' + str(i+1) for i in range(10)]
index = ['Row ' + str(i+1) for i in range(100)]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100,10), columns=columns,index=index)
df[df<.7] = np.nan

#creating the dictionary where each key is a row name
df_dict = {row : pd.DataFrame(df.loc[row].dropna()).transpose() for row in df.index}

#printing all the output
for key in natsort.natsorted(df_dict.keys())[:5]:      #using [:5] to limit output
    print(df_dict[key], '\n')

Out[1]:
       Column 1  Column 4  Column 7  Column 9  Column 10
Row 1  0.790282  0.710857  0.949141   0.82537   0.998411 

       Column 5  Column 8  Column 10
Row 2  0.941822  0.722561   0.796324 

       Column 2  Column 4  Column 5  Column 6
Row 3    0.8187  0.894869  0.997043  0.987833 

       Column 1  Column 7
Row 4  0.832628    0.8349 

       Column 1  Column 4  Column 6
Row 5  0.863212  0.811487  0.924363
```

Instead of printing, you could write the output to a text file; maybe that's the type of document that you could look at (and search) to compare to the input tables.  Bute not that even though the printed data are tabular, **they can't be made into a DataFrame without accepting that there will be missing data for rows which don't have entries for all columns**.